# Add Validators to your substrate node template

Tags: substrate-node-template, nodes, substrate-front-end, substrate-parachain-template, bootnode

I generate key pairs on my first machine and modify the customspec.json and generate customspecRaw.json and distribute my customspecRaw.json to other machines I want to add. Okay My question is that It is necessary to generate keys on other machines too and modify their customspec.json or just share first machine customespecRaw.json and run the command to start the 2nd node.??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new `customSpecRaw.json` for every node, just share the first nodes `customSpecRaw.json` and provides it node ID and IP address to the node that needs to join the network. You can refer to this [link](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/simulate-network/) , for further instructions everything is explained step by step there.

Comment: And one more thing, Do i  need to create Key pairs on all nodes?

Comment: When starting the network you need to provide key pair for every node.

Comment: I did all the things mentioned on  tutorials , I started first node  , do I have to create key pairs on 2nd node(different  machine )and add them to customspec.json or just need to create on first node ??

Comment: While creating customSpec you need to add the keys for all the nodes, it doesn't matter where you create it.

Comment: You mean I need to add aura and grandpa key of  node2 in node 1 when  creating customspec.json? And then create customspecRaw.json and distribute to the other nodes

Comment: yes thats what you need to do